# localy ringed space, schemes,sheaf

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry

I would like to start ideas of localy ringed space, schemes, sheaf and their uses and properties and examples from very elementary level. would any one suggest me a book or notes which explains those things with lots of examples may be some pictures etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A book from which I learned a lot is *Algebraic Geomtry - An Introduction* by Daniel Perrin. Chapter 3 gives a nice motivation for sheaves and locally ringed spaces, without being too abstract. Also, I recommend *The geometry of schemes* by Joe Harris and David Eisenbud.

But you won't get everything from these books. For more advanced stuff, I recommend the (classic) *Algebraic Geometry* by Robin Hartshorne and the (not-so classic but very good) *Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves* by Qing Liu.

Comment: And by the way, the first two books I mentionned are available online through the library of my university; it may be the case that they are also available through yours

Comment: it would be great, if you give the link of pdf of those?

Comment: @Makuasi You will have to look through your university's library. For example, if I search for *The geometry of schemes*, I get the following: http://mcgill.worldcat.org/title/geometry-of-schemes/oclc/41580624&referer=brief_results , and it tells me that there is an eletronic copy available. But this depends on what kind of subscriptions you university has, and the resources provided by the library.

Comment: ok dear sir, i will collect it. :)